# JNLP application not running exec method with newer versions of Java

Tags: java-8, runtime, java-web-start, jnlp

I am launching a JNLP application which uses a jar file which executes a command using

*Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);*

The *cmd* is working with older versions of jdk like jdk1.8.0_202 but doesn't runs with newer versions like jdk1.8.0_351.

*cmd* is a command to call a .exe file.

I tried changing *cmd* to call another .exe file which is working fine.

The problem is with the particular exe file only but cannot figure it out.

I tried using InputStreams and ErrorStreams but cannot see anything.